Callback function error in std::async call
Using this code sample to add multithreading callback mechanism for the following code using std::function and std::bind.
void MyClass::afterCompleteCallback(string stsstr)
{
     CString strResult;
     strResult.Format(L"You received: %s", stsstr); //expected "My Output 1"
     GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC)->SetWindowTextW(strResult);
}

void MyClass::StartMyThread()
{
    auto callback = std::bind(&MyClass::afterCompleteCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1);
    string _data = "My Input 1"
    _aStatus = std::async(std::launch::async, longRunningFunction(callback), data);
}


void MyClass::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    StartMyThread();
}

I am modifying the longRunningFunction(callback) with

auto _aStatus = std::async(std::launch::async,
longRunningFunction(callback), data);

but getting the error no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list error.
My end goal is to pass some str data to thread OnButtonClick() event and get a str result from the thread via callback and update in the MFC TextEdit control. How can I achieve this?

Your _aStatus MUST be a member variable of your class. 1) otherwise async will synchronize right away. When std::future goes out of scope it synchronizes. 2) You want the destructor of  MyClass to block until the asynchronous call has finished (using the fact that the std::future member will synchronize at destruction)

Note : show ALL your relevenat code, the call to std::async is missing and personally I prefer using lambda expressions over std::bind.  (no messing around with placeholders)

The problem with std::async(std::launch::async, longRunningFunction(callback), data) is that you call the function longRunningFunction, and try to pass what it returns to std::async.

@PepijnKramer Added my relevant code.

_aStatus = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]{ afterCompleteCallback(_data); and again make sure _aStatus is a member (you still don't show the member variables and/or destructor of your class).

And the next problem you have is that you cannot update windows controls (GetDlgItem) from background threads. It is just better to send a invalidate message to the control and let it redraw based on the value of a member variable holding the updated string.

@Someprogrammerdude Yes what's the correct syntax to call the longRunningFunction in a new thread? How do I pass the callback arg to the thread call?

A lambda, as suggested by @PepijnKramer, is what I would recommend.

Won't the data acquisition part be separate to the UI one? That is, a GUI application (in MFC) and a non-MFC dll retrieving the data and sending them to the application? Then you first have to define the function prototype. And for simplicity, it would be best to be reduced to a C interface. I would suggest the following parameters: the input string (buffer), and a callback function (function pointer) that will be delivering the results, called by the worker thread. It will be implemented by the application.

A safe way to accomplish this would be to use sending message(s) from your thread, something like:
void MyClass::longRunningFunction(callback, HWND hWnd)
{
//  longRunning_task
    ::PostMessage(hWnd, WMU_NOTIFYTHREAD, WMU_JOBDONE, 0/*items_received*/);
}

and then:
// CMyDialog implementation

    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialog)
        //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyDialog)
        //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
        ON_MESSAGE(WMU_NOTIFYTHREADUPDATE, &CMyDialog::OnNotifyThread)
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()

and
LRESULT CMyDialog::OnNotifyThread(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case WMU_JOBDONE:
        CString sText{};
        sText.format(_T("You received: %d"), lParam);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC)->SetWindowTextW(sText);
        break;
    }

    return 1;
}


It appears that you want to execute a long-running method to generate some output and then you want to display that output in the GUI thread. What you need is an event loop (MFC probably has one). Your worker thread/thread-pool should run the long-running function, store the result somewhere, and post a message to the event loop. The event loop then needs to pick up the result and display it. I am not very familiar with workings of MFC specifically, but look around for these concepts and you will find how to achieve what you're trying to do.
